# AWS policy application failure for a topic with strange error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "SNS:Subscribe",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:*:*:test-pipeline"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "SNS:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:*:*:test-pipeline"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am not sure why I get the error as

```
Error code: InvalidParameter - Error message: An error occurred while setting the attribute access policy. Invalid parameter: Every policy statement must have a unique ID
```

The ID is not mandatory, and when I have only one block in the array, it just works

Comment: FYI you can make this one statement with `"Action": ["SNS:Subscribe", "SNS:Publish"]` because both of your statements are the same other than the action.

Comment: I do know that and thanks for it. But why is this not working is what is very hard for me to grasp

Answer (score 8):

Its optional, but not for every service, such as SNS. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_sid.html):

> Some AWS services (for example, Amazon SQS or Amazon SNS) might **require this element** and have uniqueness requirements for it.